# Is the error upon Sending or Receiving? Full message not sent or message not decoded properly

Tags: php, c++, winapi, unicode

So I am posting some data from my C++ desktop application to my server (a PHP script).

Not all the post data is received by the server. Where do you think the error is happening? At server-side decoding (of UTF-8) or at client-side transmission?

C++ Code: Note its Unicode. If I send ASCII the script receives/decodes the whole post data string:

```
static TCHAR hdrs[] =
    _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\0\0");
static TCHAR frmdata[] =
    _T("name=John+Doe&auth=abc\0\0");  // use 2 null chars just incase
static LPSTR accept[2] = { "*/*", NULL };


HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen(_T("MyAgent"),
    INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
// error checking removed but none of these fail

HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, _T("mydomain.com"),
    INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);

HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, _T("POST"),
    _T("upload.php"), NULL, NULL, (LPCWSTR*)&accept, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 1);


HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, _tcslen(hdrs), frmdata, _tcslen(frmdata));
// The above function returns true and I query the response code and its HTTP 200 ok so sending is working
```

Simple PHP script:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents("post.txt", $data);  // outputs "name=John+D" so its missing text

// To make things even more confusing
echo mb_detect_encoding($data); // outputs ASCII!!!???
```

Weirdly if I send as ASCII the script receives/decodes the whole post data

```
static char hdrs[] =
    _T("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\0\0");
static char frmdata[] =
    _T("name=John+Doe&auth=abc\0\0"); 
static LPCSTR accept[2] = { "*/*", NULL };

...

HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata, strlen(frmdata));
// The above function returns true and I query the response code and its HTTP 200 ok so sending is working
```

With ASCII post.txt contains `name=John+Doe&auth=abc`. So where would the error be occurring? Is it not the whole post string is sent or the PHP script is not handling unicode correctly?

Comment: `_T("... charset=UTF-8");` - That's a lie as soon as you `#define _UNICODE`. You need to learn about character encodings, and what those generic-text mappings are (see [Ansi- and Wide-character functions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/winapi/2450/ansi-and-wide-character-functions/8085/introduction#t=201607250227403955238)).

Comment: @IInspectable yes, that was just a test. Even without specifying the charset it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't send all characters. You also specify encoding incorrectly.**

`wchar_t *s1 = L"abc";` is not UTF-8 encoded
`char *s2 = "abc";` happens to be UTF-8 encoded (that's a nice property of of UTF-8) but with this notation you are limited to latin characters. See example below.

_tcslen(frmdata) returns number of characters, not bytes. The string takes more bytes than  characters if you define Unicode. Your server expects UTF-8 byte sequence but the actual encoding is not UTF-8.

Few examples on how to specify literal strings [encoding in C++ 11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

```
// Greek small letter tau
char const *tau8 = u8"\u03C4"; // UTF-8
char16_t tau16 = u'\u03C4';    // UTF-16
wchar_t tau32 = U'\U000003C4'; // UTF-32
```